# How can I set java script function to my menu bar item in Kendo UI

Tags: c#, php, javascript, razor, kendo-ui

I m developing a web page using Kendo UI. I want to change language of my web page.How can I set java script function to my menu bar item ?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Menu()
      .Name("Menu")
items.Add().Text("Language");
  })
)
```

Comment: `How can I set java script function to my menu bar item` -- I don't understand the question. Could you explain?

Comment: I want set action to my menu bar item. For that i think i should hv write a java script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you.[Kendo menu API](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/menu/api.html)

This is [a similar question](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-complete-for-asp-net-mvc/menu/http-post-request-from-kendo-mvc-ui-menu-item.aspx) like yours

Also try this

```
@(Html.Kendo().Menu()
          .Name("Menu")
          .Items(items =>
              {
                 items.Add().Text("Language").Action("Index", "Home");
              })
      )
```

Comment: thanx for help. But this is for change web page. I want to add funtion to menu item.